# Form and Processing page on different domains. Any risks?

Tags: forms, security, encryption, https

If I have a form on a HTTPS site and my processing page (which is also HTTPS) is on a completely different domain, will the data be secure?

For example:
https://example.com has a form with action="https://processingpage.com" is there any risk with the data that is sent from the form?

Can it be intercepted? Does it have to be encrypted?

Any help on this matter would be great.

Comment: Might be better suited for the InformationSecurity site.

Comment: Cross-posted to Security.SE: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/144753/45523 this post can be deleted now.